# Spring Mongo Template calling mapreduce remotely

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a map reduce function to create a new collection that I am calling through my spring template.

```
    public void mapReduce(String mapFile, String reduceFile, String finalizeFile, String collection_out )
{
    mongoTemplate.mapReduce(COLLECTION_NAME, mapFile, reduceFile,
            options().finalizeFunction(finalizeFile).outputCollection(collection_out), DBObject.class);

}
```

However the method `mongoTemplate.mapReduce` returns the collection, I do not want this as it is crappy out my,

```
Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" Exception in thread "application-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My new collection is returning about 8k of results, I want this created in mongo but not returned to Java.

Comment: Have you read the output? And noticed that small hint [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)?

Comment: yeah I tried get the list back, still ran out of memory.

Comment: Maybe you want to increase the memory available to the JVM.

Comment: I want it to be a remote call to the DB and not involved a resultset in the JVM

Comment: It is not really a matter what you _want_. You Tomcat can't allocate memory it needs. Unless this is fixed, we can't find out what's going on.